# spring не читает конфигурацию бд из application.yml

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

Дропнул схему MySQL Workbench с названием "search_engine", теперь в конфигурации могу писать что угодно, spring запускает приложение безотказно. Соответственно, никаких таблиц в схеме не создается. В чем может быть проблема?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SearchEngine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: user
    password: pass
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/search_engine?useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show-sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

Answer (score 0):

а эта штука у Вас есть :

> Configuration configuration = new
> Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);

Он должен заниматься читкой.. Правда, я создавал таблицы ручками

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).